# How to deal with "Too many load/unload tasks running: try again later

Tags: teradata

I have tried the fastload and it worked all right the first time .   When I ran it the second time i got `Too many load/unload tasks running: try again later` . Then   I closed the connection and tried again and it worked .

Then i tried to replicate everything again to check whether closing connection deals with `Too many load/unload tasks running: try again later` and was not able to fastload .

Does closing connection guarantee no problem with `Too many load/unload tasks running: try again later`  ?  If no , then what does ?  Is there any command that deletes ALL miltithread `loads` associated with the `Connection` so that one can proceed with fastload without this error ?

Comment: What version of Teradata? Do you have access to Viewpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the database version Teradata constrains the number of concurrent load utilities that are permitted to run. In releases prior to Teradata 13 or 13.10 this limit was managed in the DBS Controls. Starting with Teradata 13 or 13.10 utilities limits were managed by Workload Management ruleset via Viewpoint.

It is not uncommon for load utilities to be further constrained during the time period which is reserved for end users or the business.Something else that may come into play is whether you are running on an Appliance or an Enterprise class system which you haven't indicated.

If you are not the DBA of the environment I would suggest consulting with the DBA responsible for the environment.

Comment: Thank you . So I am using teradata 14 . There is no way i can talk to the dba . as far as i understand there is nothing i can do . whenever i encounter this issue again , i will just have to ` wait and try later ` as it prompts , right ?

Comment: If you have not contact with the DBA, you are stuck waiting and trying again at a later time.